# POST API data does not save in the mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, body-parser

I create the rest API using express. When I am making a POST request with the body then I didn't get the response the data which I am sending. I am getting the only objectID and version and data are not saving in the MongoDB database. The first code is route making API request, second is for schema and model and third code section is for the running the server. In the first section, I made a post request which will send the data to the MongoDB and store in the file, for storing data in the MongoDB schema and models are created in the second section. The third section of code is used for the run the server.

```
const express = require('express')
const route_ = express.Router()
const proSchema_ = require('../models/productModel')

route_.post('/product', function(req, res, next){

    console.log("request",req.body)
    proSchema_.create(req.body).then(function(PRODUCT){
        res.send(PRODUCT)
    }).catch(next)
})




const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const schema = mongoose.Schema

// creating schema & model

const prodSchema = new schema({
     pName: String,
     quantity: String
});

const Product_ = mongoose.model('product', prodSchema);

module.exports = Product_




const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const Route = require('./router/router')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const urlencodedBodyParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
})
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/curdApp', { useNewUrlParser: true })
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise

app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(urlencodedBodyParser)

app.use('/api',Route)

// error handling
app.use(function(err, req, res, next){
    res.status(422).send({
        error: err.message
    })
})

app.listen( process.env.port || 4000, function(){
    console.log('Server is listening on port: 4000 ')
})


I want the POST API response with data which I request in the body. I get the response only ObjectID and __v:0. I am getting issue while making a request.
```

Comment: Check the MongoDB to check whether the data is exists or not

Comment: Initially, MongoDB is empty, when I hit POST API, then ObjectID and __v is shown in MongoDB